# jquery add content to div that not exist?

Tags: jquery, ajax

My problem is, I have one page with one jquery function, when submit a text it puts the text content into #post div.

But this jquery is used in other 5 pages and in this pages I have not the #post div to put its content. It is purposeful, for what I'm doing.

```
$('#submit').click(function (e) {
    var form = $('#form32');
    var submit = $('#submit');

    $.ajax({
      url: '/p.php',
      type: 'POST',
      cache: false,
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: function(data){
          $(data).hide().prependTo('#post').fadeIn(1000);
      },
    });
});
```

my question here is simple, can I just continue with this script in the pages with no #post div? or it can cause some eventual bizarre error?

Comment: I am not sure what you're asking.  If a div doesn't exist you can't put anything in it.

Comment: Check if #post exist, like that: $("#post:visible")

Comment: The only "error" is that the data you receive will not be displayed anywhere on the page.

Comment: thank you friends for your answers! I don't want to put anything in it if it does not exist, I just want to know if I need to check something to avoid any error in pages that div not exist...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I tend to use this concept a lot:

```
var $elem = $('#element');
if ($elem.length) {
    // I can use $elem!
    $elem.appendTo($otherElem);
}
```

Applied to your example:

```
var $post = $('#post');
if ($post.length) {
    $(data).hide().prependTo($post).fadeIn(1000);
}
```

(This would avoid any unnecessary console errors/logs/etc)

Comment: @RickJoe Rick and Meeseeks in the same post.

Answer (score 4):

jQuery fails silently if the selector is not found so you shouldn't have any unusual behaviors using those selectors on pages where they don't exist.

Simple example:

```
$('no_such_element');
```

You could put that anywhere with no problem